# Spark BigQuery Connector, set EU location

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, google-bigquery

I have been using the BQ connector that Google provides and contributing to another connector that abstracts the logic away

my question is how can I write to an EU location via the spark API using the `saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset`?

Setting the location via the hadoop conf isnt enough it seems

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this by just writing myself a new connector. You can view it [here](https://github.com/samelamin/spark-bigquery)